# Install Debian Based OS without Live CD/USB

Tags: linux, livecd

After having a few problems installing a Debian based Linux system, I was curious, **Is it possible to fully install a Linux OS to an empty partition without booting a live/installation CD/USB?** (I currently have an empty ext4 partiton that is the target for the install)

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What do you mean by "install/extract an OS"? At any rate, you are asking two questions. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I mean the live CD install fails to install. So I need to install without a live CD.

Comment: Then ask about that. "Install hangs, how can I get it to go through?" or something like that.

Comment: Can we get a picture of what the screen shows when it hangs?

Comment: I can try to get one. It essentially hang as soon as it hits the select language screen. English is selected by default. No input seems to work.

Comment: My question is the **BOLD** print.

Comment: You should be able to install Kali from a CD/DVD or flash drive.  The fact that it hangs on both means there's a problem.  Did you verify the hash on the ISO?  Are you asking if there's an installation mechanism that doesn't involve any form of live session?  Many Linux distros have an install disk that doesn't use a live session.  There are also various other ways to install.  However, that won't fix whatever your problem is.  You are likely to just identify another installation method that fails for the same underlying reason.  Why not focus on solving the actual problem?

Comment: The hash is correct. I am having trouble with the text install. I was able to get it installed by running the "Live" version then using the install from there. But my question is speculation about how I can install a Linux OS without having to boot to a "secondary" medium. This is less of a "how do I fix this?" And more of "how could I do this?" Sorry for all the confusion my poor word choice is causing...

Comment: The question should be a bit clearer now...

Comment: Can you download the .iso and use Virtual Clone Drive to mount the .iso and run it that way?